# Superadditivity of natural density

Tags: measure-theory

For prime number $p \in \mathbb{P}$, define a countably infinite subset $A_p \subset \mathbb{N}$

$A_p = \{p^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} + 1\}$

For example, $A_2 = \{2^n \mid n \in \mathbb{N} + 1\}$.

It is known that

- the cardinality of this example set is countable infinity: $|A_2| = \aleph_0$
- the natural density of this example set is zero: $d(A_2) = 0$.
- finite additivity is satisfied: $d(A_2 \cup A_3) = d(A_2) + d(A_3) = 0$.

However, imagine
$\bigcup_{p \in \mathbb{P}} A_p$ (Note that $A_p \cap A_q = \emptyset$ for any $p \ne q \in \mathbb{P}$).

$\bigcup_{p \in \mathbb{P}} A_p = \{2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,13,16,17,19,23,25,27,29,31,32,\cdots\}$

It seems dense in natural number.

Is the density of this countable union really zero: $d(\bigcup_{p \in \mathbb{P}} A_p) = 0$?

Is there any possibility that there is a infinite-superadditivity in natural density:
$d(\bigcup_{p \in \mathbb{P}} A_p) \ge \sum_{p \in \mathbb{P}} d(A_p) = 0$?

Comment: What does $\mathbb N+1$ mean?

Comment: Should say:  even $\mathbb N$ is ambiguous.  Some people take that to refer to integers $≥1$, others allow $0\in \mathbb N$.  To avoid confusion, I suggest you write out $A_2$ more explicitly.  Is $A_2=\{1,2,4,8, \cdots\}$ or $\{2,4,8,\cdots\}$ or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asymptotic density of powers of primes](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859736/asymptotic-density-of-powers-of-primes)